# column slug is not unique

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, slug

When I add data from a my form and get this error.
IntegrityError at /open_shop/
column slug is not unique

But tested and slug it unique

```
class OpenShopForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shop


class OpenShop(CreateView):
    model = Shop
    form_class = OpenShopForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    f = form.save(commit=False)
    f.submitter = self.request.user
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        f = OpenShopForm(self.request.POST)
    f.save()

    return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("profile", kwargs={'slug': self.request.user})
```

If I add the same through the admin, it works correctly

This code does not save pictures:

```
class OpenShop(CreateView):
    model = Shop
    form_class = OpenShopForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.submitter = self.request.user
        f.save()
        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profile", kwargs={'slug': self.request.user})

{% extends "base.html"%}
{% block content %}


   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'addproduct' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
          <p>
            {{form.title.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product name:</label>
            {{ form.title }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{form.slug.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Slug:</label>
            {{ form.slug }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{form.catalog.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product catalog:</label>
            {{ form.catalog }}

        <p>
            {{form.subcatalog.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product subcatalog:</label>
            {{ form.categories }}
        </p>

        <p>
            {{form.description.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product descriptions:</label>
            {{ form.description }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{form.price.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product price:</label>
            {{ form.price }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{form.sale_price.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product sale price:</label>
            {{ form.sale_price }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{form.is_active.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product activity:</label>
            {{ form.is_active }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{form.is_featured.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product featured:</label>
            {{ form.is_featured }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{form.quantity.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product quantity:</label>
            {{ form.quantity }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{form.shop.errors}}
            <label class="txtField" for="id_subject">Product shop:</label>
            {{ form.shop }}
        </p>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

{% endblock %
```

}

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name=u'Image', upload_to="product_pic", blank=True)
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog)
    subcatalog = models.ManyToManyField(Subcatalog)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="Describe product")
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="product vendor")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: doesn't `f = OpenShopForm(self.request.POST)` dismiss the `f.submitter` line completely? If I'm understanding correctly, the submitter is the slug, so if you'r overriding that line then no slug is assigned

Comment: and using `request.POST` saves pictures?? That makes zero sense, as files are transferred to `request.FILES` and not `request.POST`.

Comment: also not saves. I stuck capitally ...

Comment: well according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) you don't need to call `save`, it is supposed to do so automatically. can you share your html form?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you have those two lines beginning `if self.request.method == 'POST'` in `form_valid`. That method is only called if the form is valid, which can only happen if it was instantiated from a POST in the first place. As yuvi noted, inside that statement you're replacing the existing form with a new one based on the POST, overwriting what you previously did to set `submitter`.

Comment: These fields have been added because they did not save pictures from the form.  `class OpenShop(CreateView):
    model = Shop
    form_class = OpenShopForm

    def form_vaalid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.submitter = self.request.user
        f.save()
        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profile", kwargs={'slug': self.request.user})`

Comment: @wadadaaa please edit that code into your original post, it's unreadable like this

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I've never used class-based views, and the docs are rather ambiguous. but try:

```
 def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.submitter = self.request.user
    return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: `'AddproductForm' object is not callable`

Comment: try removing the first line entirely.

Comment: `IntegrityError at /addproduct/
products_product.submitter_id may not be NULL`

Comment: Oh snap. I just got it. Just assign the value to `form.instance` (not form), and you don't need to save anything or do anything else (the docs provide an [extremely similar](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) example).

Comment: unfortunately the exact same error `IntegrityError at /addproduct/
products_product.submitter_id may not be NULL`

Comment: ensure that you don’t include `submitter` in the list of fields to edit (add it to excluded fields on the form)

Answer (score 1):

It works!

```
class AddProduct(CreateView):
        model = Product
        form_class = AddproductForm

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.submitter = self.request.user
            return super(AddProduct, self).form_valid(form)
        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse("profile", kwargs={'slug': self.request.user})
```

Comment: So, essentially, this is the same as my answer